# How to install Android Package manually (without Google Play, adb install, or "Install" click)

Tags: installation, apk

### Backstory

Before we get into question, I will explain what happened in my android.

Earlier, I got random bug in my Android that causing my OS got **"Half-restored factory settings."**

By the means *Half-restored*, some of my basic configurations are reverted to default (wallpaper, Settings, LINE, Facebook, Browsers, even Google Accounts) while some apps are not reverted. *I wonder why.*

Then I found that all apps that I installed on SDCard are considered **uninstalled** by my Android, though the **ASEC** files are still there.

[image: The apps are still there in .android_secure in SDCard]

And when I looked up into **/data/data/**, all data are still there as well.

[image: via Titanium Backup. Apps considered uninstalled, yet ASEC and data are exist as well.]

Then, I tried to manually mount .asec files (tutorial [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1700536)) and successfully mount the .asec into **/mnt/asec//**. APK, data, library and configs are there as well, too.

But unfortunately, even after I mounted the asec manually, it still considered not installed yet by OS.

---

### Question

So those events and conditions raise me questions:

1. Is there any command, or configuration/text that I can edit to make those mounted ASEC apps considered installed?
2. How to reinstall those apps without losing orphaned data? (because if I reinstall the app, the app will go to **/data/app** partition and the **/data/data** will be overwritten)

Thanks for reading, I'll look forward for the answer.

---

### Additional Info

For additional info, I use ZTE N986 on 4.2.1 Android Jellybean OS (official stockrom), rooted (obviously) + Xposed.

This accident occurs whenever the android has battery collapsed (0% and turned off by itself), though it's not always (even rarely). It's just I experienced this bug numerous times and this always happens when I have 0% battery.